# Populating Select List including OptGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist, optgroup

I'm populating a select list with an array of data. Like this:

```
$(somedata).each(function() {
    $(document.createElement('option'))
        .attr('value', this.Value)
        .text(this.Text)
        .appendTo(SelectList);
});
```

How do I append `optgroups` in the same way? the array of data is a list with the properties Text, Value, OptGroup (boolean) and ordered so the OptGroup comes first followed by it's options. Like this:

```
[
    ['OptGroup1', 'OptGroup1', true]
    ['Value1', 'Value1', false]
    ['Value2','Value2',false]
    ['OptGroup2', 'OptGroup2', true]
    // ...
]
```

Comment: please post all the relevant code and show us what you have tried so far in order to solve the optgroup issue.

Comment: Tried switching if it's an optgroup item: $(document.createElement('optgroup'))
                           .attr('value', this.Value)
                           .text(this.Text).appendTo(SelectList); But that doesn't append the options as child elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward - check if 3rd value is true or false and create the proper element accordingly.

a few points though:

- optgroups are appended to the select, while options need to be appended to the last optgroup that you have added. an optgroup is a container of options, and not a title that comes before them.
- the text on the optgroup is set by the `label=""` attribute, and not value/text.

```js
$(function () {
    var somedata = [
        ['OptGroup1', 'OptGroup1', true],
        ['Value1', 'Value1', false],
        ['Value2', 'Value2', false],
        ['OptGroup2', 'OptGroup2', true],
        ['Value3', 'Value3', false],
        ['Value4', 'Value4', false]
    ];
    console.log(somedata);
    var SelectList = $("#SelectList");
    $(somedata).each(function () {
        var $newElem;
        if ($(this)[2] == false) {
            $newElem = $(document.createElement('option')).attr('value', this[1])
            .attr('label', this[0])
            .appendTo(SelectList.find("optgroup").last());
        } else {
            $newElem = $(document.createElement('optgroup')).attr('value', this[1])
            .attr('label', this[0])
            .appendTo(SelectList);;
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectList"></select>
```